# Is there a direct link to "write a review" for our business on Google that can be put in an email?

Tags: user-reviews, google-business

When we search for our client's company on Google, the Google Business listing turns up in the right hand column. At the bottom of this listing is a link to "Write a review".

Is there a way we can add a link to my client's email signature to take my client's customers straight to writing a Google review?

I understand we could enter a URL to search their company name on Google, but I would prefer something more direct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a great (and short) tutorial on how to create your Google Business Review link:
https://support.google.com/business/answer/7035772?hl=en

The synopsis is

> Go to the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id).
>
> Find your Place ID by searching under "Enter a location"
>
> The url will be `https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=`**YOUR-PLACE-ID**